# Change days to just represent integers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a data frame called date_Delta:

[image]

I would like to change NaT to 0 and I would like to change the 1 days, 8 days, etc to just 1, 8. I tried using .astype(int) and others but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `fillna` and `str` accessor

```
df.delta.fillna('0').str[0].astype(int)
```

Alternatively, can use [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html)

```
df.delta.fillna('0').str.get(0).astype(int)
```

If you have Timestamps, just use `.dt.days` accessor

```
df.delta.dt.days
```

Comment: Hey, I made a post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847132/determine-which-are-the-fastest-growing-users-in-terms-of-positive-customer-enga/52848117#52848117 Just wanted to see if you wanted to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Given the `NaT` value, it appears that you have timedelta64 objects.

To get your desired format, use the `dt` datetime accessor, convert the value to days, and fill NaNs with zero.

```
df['date_Delta'] = df['date_Delta'].dt.days.fillna(0)
```