# Determine which are the fastest growing users in terms of positive customer engagement

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have this data set:

[image]

I am being asked: Define a metric and a corresponding function that determines which are the fastest growing users in terms of positive customer engagement over the last year. Report the top 10 users based on the metric that defines “fastest growing user”.

So far I have created a correlation matrix:

```
                   user_id  content_count  total_engagement  date_Delta
user_id           1.000000      -0.056683          0.027150   -0.000014
content_count    -0.056683       1.000000          0.215149   -0.007097
total_engagement  0.027150       0.215149          1.000000    0.002337
date_Delta       -0.000014      -0.007097          0.002337    1.000000
```

As you can see content_count and total_engagement have the best correlation component.

What I am thinking of doing next is to create a graph of each user_id and their total_engagement to see the overall linearity which will give some indication as to which users had a strong increasing total_engagement.

Although, I am overall a bit confused with how to define a metric for the question posed. I guess I just want to make this post to see if I could get anyone to purpose some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have new field which will tell daily engagement for user_id. something like total_management/date_delta which will give actual day engagement.